# Show data if current time is between start and end time of json data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

I'm trying to implement some functionality into my code but I'm struggling to reach the end result.
Lets say I've got a json file with these fields:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "genre": "Comedy",
    "startTime": "10:00",
    "endTime": "10:30"
}

{
    "id": 2,
    "genre": "horror",
    "startTime": "22:00",
    "endTime": "23:30"
}
```

What I want to do is only display data that has the following condition:

```
if currentTime is between startTime && endTime
```

at the moment the result I get is ALL objects in an array being displayed one by one (it should only show those within the start and end time). So, to clarify further: If the current time is 10:10, I should only be shown the "Comedy" genre.

The code (I'm using moment js).

```
const [active, setActive] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => {
    let currentTime = moment().format("hh:mm")
    const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
        if (moment(currentTime).isBetween(exampleData.startTime), (exampleData.endTime)) {
            setActive((active) => (active + 1) % data.example.length);
        } else {
            return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
        }
    }, 5000);
}, []);

const cData = data.exampleData[active];

return (
    { cData.genre }
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you will have to use the constructor of moment with a string and a format to transform `"10:30"` into an moment object.

> moment(String, String);

```js
const items = [{
    "id": 1,
    "genre": "Comedy",
    "startTime": "10:00",
    "endTime": "10:30"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "genre": "horror",
    "startTime": "22:00",
    "endTime": "23:30"
  }];
  
const actives = items.filter(item => {
  const startMoment = moment(item.startTime, "HH[:]mm"); // Create moment object
  const endMoment = moment(item.endTime, "HH[:]mm"); // Create moment object
  return moment().isBetween(startMoment, endMoment); // Compare with current time
});

console.log(actives);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```